# SpTBX: can i have MultiLine prop for tabs control

Tags: delphi, sptbxlib

I refer to `TSpTbxTabSet` with many tabs. Can i have multi-line view like `TPageControl` has? i can't find such a prop. if i add lot of tabs (e.g. 20 tabs with text "wwwwwwwwwww"), they're truncated in 1 line (i need to see N lines of tabs so all 're visible).

Answer (score 0):

No `MultiLine`, but `TabAutoFit` prop exists for tabset, which makes needed thing.